# Rectangular prism optimization using extreme values

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> A box with a rectangular base, whose length is twice its width, is to have a closed top. The area of the material in the box is to be $192in^2$. What should the dimensions of the box be in order to have the largest possible volume?

$$l = 2w$$

So,

$$S= 2(lw)+ 2(wh)+ 2(lh)
\\ = 2(2w^2)+ 2(wh)+2(2wh)
\\ = 4w^2+2wh+4wh
\\ = 4w^2 +6wh$$

$$V=lwh
\\ = 2w \cdot w \cdot h
\\ = 2w^2 \cdot h$$

Now,

$${dV \over dw} = 4w\cdot {dh \over dw}
\\ 0= 4w \cdot {dh \over dw}
\\ {dh \over sw} = -4w$$

and

$${dS \over dw} = 4w^2 +6wh
\\ = 8w + 6 \cdot {dh \over dw}
\\ = 8w + 6(-4w)
\\ = -16w$$

I think I'm lost. I don't know what to do next. Could someone help find the solution? Thanks!

Comment: You know that $4w^2+6wh=192$, so that $h=-4w+32/w$ and $V=-8w^3+64w$.

Comment: Such optimization problems may be solved using Lagrange multipliers method. The objective is the volume, the constrain is the surface area. (2 variables, 1 constrain equation -- 1 multiplier) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers

Answer (score 1):

Hint

If you wish to apply Lagrange Multiplier method, after simplification of V,S

$$S1 = S/2 , V1 = V/2 $$

$$ \frac{\partial S1_h} {\partial V1_h} =\frac{\partial S1_w} {\partial V1_w}$$

$$ \rightarrow w/h = 3/2. $$